# .load() not loading script tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, load

I am loading the footer for a website I am creating using the .load() function so I do not have to replace it on each site page everytime time I make a change.

I am using this code to load it currently:

```
$('.footer_load').load('includes/footer.html footer');
```

But as I have found out from my research, this only loads the HTML of the footer page, and not any script tags or dynamic content I may have designed into the page.

For example, I have a  tag on the footer that automatically updates the copyright year.

What code can I append to what I have above, to not only load the html of the footer, but also any and all scripts and dynamic content that may be within that page?

Help! I have searched high and low, and tried several codes, but cannot get anything to work, and I am at a loss for how to code this / novice in this part of JQuery to write it myself. Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the verbose answer. Here is how you might want to start. In your example, you mention you want to load new footer HTML and then execute a script manipulating data that's been added to the DOM; in your case a copyright. Here is how I would do it:

Keep your Javascript you want executed out of the new footer HTML file.

```
// Load the new footer html
$("#footer").load("includes/footer.html", function() {

    // Once HTML is loaded, call your script file that manipulates the data.
    $.getScript("scripts/updateCopyRight.js");
});
```

---

Now, what might updateCopyRight.js look like? Perhaps something like this:

```
// Self executing clojure
(function($) {

    // Change the HTML data with the current year.
    $("#SOME_ID_TO_BE_UPDATED").html(new Date().getFullYear())

})(window.jQuery)
```

This might not be a perfect solution for you, but I hope this maybe gets you on the right path.

Comment: This is not quiet what I was looking for, but does help me with another project. I was hoping more for a script that would load all <script> tags, the copyright is not the only one that is coded into the footer, it is just one of many.